System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Could not find file 'C:\
This is my connection string
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\BaronBHdb.mdb");
But it happened could not find my file 'C:\BaronBHdb.mdb,
even though if I put the exact whole location connection string of my database still same error I got
anyone please can help this problem
I really appreciate it
By the way I'm new in C#
Thank you in advance
This just a simple practice login form in visual studio
